# How to write context free grammar aspect the priority of operations in antlr4

Tags: antlr4, context-free-grammar

we knew the priority of logical operation from strong to low:
Not 
And
Or
I want to add logical operation to my grammar in way respect the priority of logical operation. ... 
My grammar is:

```
   expression : factor ( PLUS factor | MINUS factor )* ;
 factor : term ( MULT term | DIV term )* ;
 term : NUMBER | ID | PAR_OPEN expression PAR_CLOSE ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ANTLR3 and ANTLR 4, you can doe something like this:

```
expression
 : or_expression
 ;

// lowest precedence
or_expression
 : and_expression ( '||' and_expression )*
 ;

and_expression
 : rel_expression ( '&&' rel_expression )*
 ;

rel_expression
 : add_expression ( ( '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' ) add_expression )*
 ;

add_expression
 : mult_expression ( ( '+' | '-' ) mult_expression )*
 ;

mult_expression
 : unary_expression ( ( '*' | '/' ) unary_expression )*
 ;

unary_expression
 : '-' atom
 | atom
 ;

// highest precedence
atom
 : NUMBER
 | ID
 | '(' expression ')'
 ;
```

And with ANTLR4, you can also write it like this (which is equivalent to the grammar above!):

```
expression
 : '!' expression
 | expression ( '*' | '/' ) expression               // higher than '+' | '-'
 | expression ( '+' | '-' ) expression               // higher than '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' 
 | expression ( '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' ) expression // higher than '&&'
 | expression '&&' expression                        // higher than '||'
 | expression '||' expression
 | NUMBER
 | ID
 | '(' expression ')'
 ;
```

Comment: So I must only to write :        expression : '!' expression |   expression '&&' expression // higher than '||' | expression '||' expression |  factor ( PLUS factor | MINUS factor )* ;   @Bart